# Minimizer of a multivariable function and iteration through Newton's method

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

I got stuck on the following question.

> Find the minimizer for $$f (x_1,x_2) = \frac 12 (x_1^2 - x_2)^2 + \frac 12 (1-x_1)^2$$ and compute one iteration for minimizing $f$ from point $(2,2)$. Also, is this a good step?

Comment: You can find the extrema by solving $\nabla f(x) = 0$. As for the iteration, just apply Newton's method (you'll have to compute the gradient and the hessian.

Comment: i did f'(x1)=0 and f'(x2) =0 and found (1,1) as the critical point but didn't know what to do after.

Comment: I was confused because (1,1) is a root so does it have to be min/max? I wasn't sure how to chech min/max using f''() because this was a multivariable function.

Comment: Checking whether it's a minimum or a maximum can be done by computing the Hessian and checking whether it's positive/negative semi-definite at the given point. You would need the Hessian for the iteration step anyways.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x_1,x_2)$ is a well known test function. It is the [Rosenbrock function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function). The Newton method

$$
X_{k+1}=X_k - H^{-1}_k \nabla f_k
$$

gives

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 & x_2 & f(x_1,x_2)\\
 2 & 2 & 2.5 \\
 1.8 & 2. & 0.3208 \\
 1.05926 & 3.2 & 0.15229 \\
 1.03101 & 0.573333 & 0.000480989 \\
 1.00005 & 1.06217 & \text{4.603702725}*{10}^{-7} \\
 1. & 0.999141 & \text{4.47192928}*{10}^{-15} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

[image]